# How can i integrate my app with my widget?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-manifest

I have made an application as well as a widget called world clock.

But I don't know how to integrate both, I mean integrating the widget with the application. I think I have to made some manifest changes. But I am totally blind regarding this. I need some help.

Comment: do you mean publish/package them into one application?

Comment: package them into one application.

Comment: Did u find any solution??
I am having the same issue....

Comment: This is what I used, http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-essentials-enhancing-your-applications-with-app-widgets/ but my accepted/upvoted answer was deleted because it was a link only. Hope it helps someone looking though, helped me and OP.

Answer (score 1):

They need to be in the same project, and your manifest file needs to have the "this is a launchable activity" signature for the one that starts the non-widget stuff, and you widget activity needs to have the "this is a widget, make it available as such" signature. Code example to follow shortly if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Thanx a lot. But it will be better for me if you can provide me a code example?